# left join using comma separated column using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am working on an asp.net application with SQL server database. This db has two tables Vacancies and `dutystations`. Vacancies table has a column named `dutystationId` which stores ids of `dutystations` in comma separated list like this:

2,12,15,18,19,23

Now I want to show this vacancy in grid and I have used left join like this:

**QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.hr_Vacancies 
CROSS APPLY dbo.hr_Split(dbo.hr_Vacancies.DutyStationID, ',') AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_DutyStations 
ON s.Data = dbo.hr_DutyStations.DutyStationID
```

and in `xsd`, I have set `vacancyid` as primary key. but I get error:

**ERROR**

```
Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
```

If I remove this constraint, I get 6 rows. I want to show one row only. How can I do this?

Comment: Which _one row_ do you want to show?

Comment: i want one row to be shown with all dutystations as comma separated

Comment: Don't get it, but you also can use `IN` as condition.

Comment: Where+/what is this `xsd` you speak of? And what does it have to do with your query?

Comment: So in your query you want to change a list of IDs to a list of names, like 1,2,6 -> alpha, beta, zeta?

Answer (score 4):

I stopped reading here:

> Vacancies table has a column named dutystationId which stores ids of dutystations in comma seperated list

That is your problem right there. If you have comma separated values in an RDBMS, specifically if they contain foreign keys to other tables, you should **halt** full stop whatever you're doing and start redesigning your database. Many-to-many relations in an RDBMS are implemented with [junction tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), and if you use them all your problems will suddenly solve themselves.

Your current design is not only hell to write SQL queries for, like this question illustraties perfectly as you cannot solve a trivial task, but it also kills performance - those calls to `hr_Split` are infinitely more computationally expensive than just doing proper joins.

[Don't fall into the XY trap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), solve the real problem first. Which is that you're even violating [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) right now.

Comment: This answer tells like it should be. Your queries become more complex, and the performance of your queries will be weak if not intolerable. Of course, it doesn't take into account legacy code and the fact that you may not have the time to redesign it. If you are still designing your database, you best dig into what Niels posted.